# How can a JavaScript routine call itself? (not recursive!)

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

my task is to do a long running JS code. This routine generate a POST request, and when its over and need to, generates another according to the answer:

```
function routine (a)
{
    var answer = createPostRequest (bla bla bla);
    if (answer)
    {
        routine (a);
    }
}
```

so it recursively calls itself as long as the answer is true. So far its good, but then browser freezes, or hangs too much. After a time, Firefox will tell me that script is running too long, and offers to stop it.
Instead of doing `routine (a);` I tried to do with a `setTimeout` with timing 1. The same things, but when I set 100 for timing, it looks ok. But there are unnecessarry waitings, plus its a subjective number (what if even that 100 causes problems?)
I need some kind of "message based" thing, like in Delphi/Windows programming: a program sends a message to itself. How can it be achived in JS?

Edit: the way I generating the request:

```
var ajax = createXmlHttp();
ajax.open ('POST', 'dsdsdsad.adsf', false);
var parameters = 'param=1';
ajax.setRequestHeader ('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.setRequestHeader ("Content-length", parameters.length);
ajax.setRequestHeader ("Connection", "close");
ajax.send (parameters);
try
{
    var answer = eval('(' + ajax.responseText + ')');
}
catch (error)
{
    alert ('Error in the answer: '+ajax.responseText);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The definition of a recursive function, is a function that calls itself.

Comment: If this "createPostRequest" is doing something *asynchronously*, then your answer is to have the function be invoked from the callback to the asynchronous operation.

Comment: thats right, but those requests cant be asynchronous

Comment: @JohnSmith: If they *can't* be asynchronous, then your browser will be locked until the requests stop.

Comment: I think you need to consider doing an asynchronous post. jQuery and Dojo provide api's to help with this. You can find further information here: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)

Comment: If the requests were actually being done synchronously you would not be seeing the behavior you described. You should post the code for `createPostRequest()`.

Comment: ok, edited, anyway I agree on I may should use jQuery....

Comment: @JohnSmith: Why would you need jQuery just for this? You already have the request code, now just make it asynchronous and set up an `onreadystatechange` handler, and you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume your `createPostRequest` makes an AJAX call that can handle a callback.

If so, make sure the request is *asynchronous* and pass it a callback that tests the condition and makes the next call if needed.

```
function createPostRequest(address, callback) {
    var ajax = createXmlHttp();
    ajax.open ('POST', address, true); // make it async

    var parameters = 'param=1';
    ajax.setRequestHeader ('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.setRequestHeader ("Content-length", parameters.length);
    ajax.setRequestHeader ("Connection", "close");

        // handle the async response
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                if (ajax.readystate == 4) {
                                   try {
                                       callback(eval('(' + ajax.responseText + ')'));
                                   } catch {
                                       callback(null);
                                   }
                                }
                              };
    ajax.send (parameters);
}
```

---

```
function routine (a) {
    createPostRequest (bla bla bla, function(answer) {
        if (answer) {
            routine (a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about not recursive call, and routine does this anyway. I would suggest observables usage, where we run function for every object in array but waiting for others to complete first, or use any generators.